# Buggy Responsive CSS website

Tags: html, css, materialize

1. **Portrait mode on Iphone 7**

https://i.imgur.com/gVjwYM7.png

2. **Landscape Mode:**

[http://i.imgur.com/M1IwCM2.png](https://i.imgur.com/M1IwCM2.png)

3. **Rotating back to portrait mode:**

[http://i.imgur.com/pbkBVZB.png](https://i.imgur.com/pbkBVZB.png)

---

Q: Why is this occurring? What can i do to fix this buggy responsive `CSS`? Background is using WRAPPER tag while form is by using materialize `css`.
Or should i make it just like this for mobile view? :

[http://i.imgur.com/Y2RXUFi.png](https://i.imgur.com/Y2RXUFi.png)

JSFIDDLE LINK AS REQUESTED:
https://jsfiddle.net/9y0r0p2q/10/

Comment: This is difficult to understand. can you provide any link or JS fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9y0r0p2q/

Comment: updated Jsfiddle. working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the landscape screenshot appears to be that it has zoomed in by changing orientation and then you have scrolled the page.

The wrapper element is currently only set to be the height of the body/html element. Which is the height of the window, not the document. That is why the background is being clipped once you scroll any further than the height of the window.

This demo might make what's happening clearer. 
https://jsfiddle.net/20n6ag61/

To fix this you could try put the background on the body instead and adjust the height of html and body elements, like so.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height:100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #054f7d, #00a7cf, #efe348, #861a54, #054f7d);
    background-size: 600%;
    background-position: 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    /* Animation */
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: gradients;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9y0r0p2q/11/

I noticed also that you are using media queries, you may want to consider adding this meta tag to the head in your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: brilliant! However, there is still this very tiny issue, How do i fix this ? its abit ugly

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Er27aG2.png As seen is the picture, i can still scroll beyond; the ugly grey gradient

Comment: My ipad is having problem as well https://i.imgur.com/UfFSWkB.jpg: Same goes for my main computer on 23 inch monitor

Comment: by adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> My main desktop view would not be like this 
https://i.imgur.com/ZL7nKIE.jpg

Comment: I fixed already. My desktop view and ipad view is working as intended. However for iphone landscape and portrait mode its not working: see this https://i.imgur.com/sH81l0C.png. https://i.imgur.com/FWB9dqd.png Also  i changed CSS to   height: 100%;
    margin:0;

Comment: i replaced wrapper with body with the same wrapper code and its working great! Thanks buddy! A kiss for you

Comment: body {
 min-height:100vh;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #054f7d, #00a7cf, #efe348, #861a54, #054f7d);
  background-size: 600%;
  background-position: 0 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  /* height: 100%; */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Animation */
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: gradients;
}